# I need to spawn Objects in certain locations with GetMouseDown but it doesn't Spawn when i press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to spawn objects with GetMouseDown Function i assigned it to a gameObject in which it's going to spawn when i press. But nothing happens when i press check the script i'm using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HerbSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Here, we declare variables.
    public GameObject objToSpawn;
    //public means the var is exposed in the inspector, which is super helpful.
 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        //let's also spawn on button press:
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition));

            if (hit.collider && hit.collider.CompareTag("Bush"))
            {
                SpawnIt();
            }
        }

        void SpawnIt()
    {
        //spawn our coin:
        Instantiate(objToSpawn, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
    }
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Also there is a problem with the Tag in here when i use Unity2D as a tag it shows Unity3D please fix that if you know anything about it. thank you

Comment: what shows unity3d as tag?

Comment: It's the website here i wanted to tag unity2D since i am working on a 2D game but the website has something wrong it keeps taging unity3D even when i edit it

Comment: sorry but there is, and all my posts are tagged with unity2D and it says use only if you are working on Unity2D games. but whatever it's not my topic it's just a glitch

Comment: my mistake then

Comment: its fine don't worry maybe someone will fix it later.

Comment: does your object have collider 2d?

Comment: oh yeah i forgt to add that thank you that was the problem